# How to make import-export save JSONField not as string

Tags: django, import-from-excel, django-import-export

I'm trying to import JSONField using django import-export, it keeps saving JSON as string (adding "" to it)

```
models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class Governorate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    data = JSONField()
    def __str__(self):
        return ("%s" %(self.name))


admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Governorate
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
from import_export import resources

class GovernorateResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Governorate

class GovernorateAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id','name', 'data')
    resources_class = GovernorateResource

admin.site.register(Governorate,GovernorateAdmin)
```

I expected the output to be: {"xx":{"xx":"xx","xx":"xx"} however it saves it as "{"xx":{"xx":"xx","xx":"xx"}"

Tried uploading XLSX and CSV.

Comment: where do you see the output? It can't save a string, because that's not valid JSON.

Comment: I see this output in the Admin page, and when I try to check the value using the django shell, it says that it "TypeError: string indices must be integers"

"{'name': {'ar': 'x', 'en':'Ahmadi'}}"

Comment: How does a row of your CSV look like? And which version of django-import-export are you using?

Comment: id,name,data,country
,Ahmadi,"{'name': {'ar': 'x', 'en':'Ahmadi'}}",1

import-export 1.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Version 1.2.0 of import-export doesn't automatically recognise the `JSONField` in your `Resource` so it just defaults to a `CharField` type. It's already added to the master branch but not released.

So just override the field to use the `JSONWidget` which is already available in version 1.2.0:

```
from import_export import fields, widgets

class GovernorateResource(resources.ModelResource):
    data = fields.Field(widget=widgets.JSONWidget())
    class Meta:
        model = Governorate
```

Comment: Weird, as you can see [here](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/1.2.0/import_export/widgets.py#L273) the widget returns `ast.literal_eval(val)` which, when I run it on the string `"{'name': {'ar': 'x', 'en':'Ahmadi'}}"`, returns the correct python dictionary. Try removing the `"` in your CSV, like you also don't have `"` around **Ahmadi**

Comment: I tried saving another word. It added quotations to it!

Comment: I mean try `{'name': 'Ahmadi'}` in the column of your csv, without the quotes. Or do it in the xlsx file, because probably you can't comma-separate if you remove the quotes (you could try to tab-separate instead).

Answer (score 0):

So basically, the import-export library was saving the JSONField() as a string. So my solution was to create a signal to check if the instance was a string or a dict. then fix it.
I tried to create a Field with the JSONWidget widget, but doesn't work.

```
models.py
@receiver(post_save, sender=Governorate)
def fix_json(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if (type(instance.data) is str):
        instance.data = eval(instance.data)
        instance.save()
        print(instance.data)
```

The Django import-export library is really good, but lacks proper documentation to be honest.