# importing an exported list JSONField turns JSON to string if JSON list is empty

Tags: django, django-import-export

I am using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57808846/12415287) from a similar question. But I would like to treat any empty fields from the import-export file as an empty list instead of None.

I have this resource:

```
some_list_json= fields.Field(attribute='some_list_json', 
    widget=JSONWidget(), 
    column_name='some_list_json')
```

With this field:

```
some_list_json = models.JSONField(default=list, blank=True, null=True)
```

When I try to export it, it doesn't show anything. And when I try to import and do some manipulation, it returns an exception.

```
'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `JSONWidget` to handle this case:

```py
class EmptyListJSONWidget(JSONWidget):
    def clean(self, value, row=None, *args, **kwargs):
        val = super().clean(value)
        if not val:
            return list()
        return val

    def render(self, value, obj=None):
        if value is []:
            return value
        return json.dumps(value)
```

Don't forget to update your resource field to reference this new widget instead of `JSONWidget`.

Note that if you export this into csv, you will get `[]` in the field, you can adjust the code to return an empty string if preferred, then import / export will work as expected.

Comment: Hello thanks! you might be able to answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69902802/clean-previous-data-django).