# Clean previous data django

Tags: django, django-import-export

I have a `JSONField` in my model and I wasn't able to clean the initial import on my resource so the data imported were treated as strings instead of lists. When I export the data it looks like this:

[image]

The ones below are the previous data from the initial `import-export` without a custom `JSONWidget`. The ones above are the data that was cleaned.

How can I then fix the current `JSONField` with the `string` and convert it to a `list`?

Comment: Is every value supposed to be an empty list or are there some values in some rows?

Comment: there are some values in some rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably you want to clean the values in the database, so that they are standardised to empty list.  If so, there are a few ways you could do this:

- A straight `UPDATE` command via SQL ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35349699/39296))
- If you can run `./manage.py shell` you should be able to filter the entries and correct the data.
- If you can run `django-admin` commands, write a script which filters and corrects the data, then use the [django-extensions runscript](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runscript.html) command.
- Create a [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/#data-migrations)

Please correct me if I have misunderstood what you are aiming to do.

Comment: Thanks, haven't tried any but I bet all these will work. However, I remembered I can just bulk update with the django-import-export to clean all the values. I'll accept it still because you did help me in cleaning the data on one of my previous questions.